# Call to a member function fetch() on boolean because of INT value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an error 
Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in {$path}
when I use LIMIT $var or OFFSET $var
But if I'll remove '... OFFSET . $offset' I won't get an error.

```
public static function getConnection(){
    $paramsPath = ROOT.'/config/db_params.php';
    $params = include($paramsPath);

    $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);
    $db->exec("set names utf8");

    return $db;
}
public static function getTask($page = 1){
    $page = intval($page);
    $offset = ($page - 1) * 3;

    $db = Db::getConnection();
    $taskList = [];

    $result = $db->query('SELECT id, user_name, user_email, title, image, tasktext, status FROM task '
            . 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET'.$offset );
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $taskList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $taskList[$i]['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
        $taskList[$i]['user_email'] = $row['user_email'];
        $taskList[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
        $taskList[$i]['image'] = $row['image'];
        $taskList[$i]['tasktext'] = $row['tasktext'];
        $taskList[$i]['status'] = $row['status'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $taskList;
}
```

Can someone explain why is that happening and how to fix it? I really need an OFFSET to make a pagination.

Comment: You need a space between `OFFSET` and the offset value, otherwise it will read `OFFSET0` instead of `OFFSET 0` or `OFFSET3` instead of `OFFSET 3`;

Comment: Oh god, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is malformed. It needs a space after `OFFSET` before the number:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT id, user_name, user_email, title, image, tasktext, status FROM task '
        . 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET '.$offset );
```